# Adjust brightness of Arduino's built-in LED with pyFirmata

Tags: led, python

I'm learning to control an Arduino using Python with pyFirmata.

I can turn the LED on and off, but how do I adjust the brightness?

Comment: Use PWM with `analogWrite()`. Google "pyfirmata analogwrite", that seems to give promising results

Comment: @chrisl when I use the PWM pin, an error appears `raise IOError("{0} is set up as an INPUT and can therefore not be written to"
OSError: Analog pin 2 is set up as an INPUT and can therefore not be written to`    how to make it as output?

Comment: Yes, you need to make it an output. I'm not sure, why this was migrated, since in the current state of the question nobody can really provide much of an answer. You need to put way more details in your question, like your code

Comment: @chrisl, it is a simple "how to" question. It doesn't require any code, because it is not a  debugging question. The answer should be a Python code snippet with use of pyFirmata.

Comment: something like https://programtalk.com/python-examples/pyfirmata.PWM/